# Close menu after click - jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to close menu after user clicks on the certain link? 
Here is a code:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".fa-bars").on("click", function () {
    $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
});
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 580px) {
  nav ul {
  max-height: 0px;
  position: relative;
  top: 62px;
  }
.showing {
  max-height: 20em;
  position: relative;
  top: 62px;
  }
nav ul li {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  }
nav a:hover::before {
  width: 0;
  }
.menu-icon {
  display: block;
  }
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide enough code to replicate your issue - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Show us your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fa-bars').on('click', function(){
    $('nav ul#menu').toggleClass('show-menu');
  })
  $('nav ul#menu a').on('click', function(){
    $('nav ul#menu').toggleClass('show-menu');
  })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e0rpuohx/1/

Answer (score -1):

To get a more specific answer we'd need to see some HTML... But this might get you on your way.

Give whatever you want to hide an id, and give the link an onclick function. Then in the function get the ID, and set display to none.

```js
function closeMenu() {
    document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="menu">
    <a href="#home">HOME</a>
    <a href=#projects">PROJECTS</a>
    <a href=#projects">INFO</a>
    <a href=#contact">CONTACT</a>
    <button onclick="closeMenu()">Close Menu</button>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```